# Got ForbiddenAttributesError when inserting an object with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ask you a little help as I'm starting with Ruby on Rails with a problem that is still bothering me after searching docs and forums.

The problem raises when trying to insert an object of a class that has an association of type "belongs to" with another class.

In this situation, after submitting in the "new" form, Rails gives me a ForbiddenAttributesError in this line of Enterprise controller :

```
@enterprise = @country.enterprises.build(params[:enterprise])
```

I don't know how it gives me that error since I'm sending all parameters from the view , and specified all parameters as white-listed in Enterprise class:

**controller/enterprises_controller.rb**

```
def new
 @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
 @enterprise = @country.enterprises.build
end


def create
 @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
 @enterprise = @country.enterprises.build(params[:enterprise])

if @enterprise.save
  redirect_to country_enterprise_url(@country,@enterprise)
else
  render :action => 'new'
end
end


private
def enterprise_params
  params.require(:enterprise).permit(:param1,:param2,:param3)
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a 'permission' private action for permitting params, but not using it when creating instance..

instead of :

`@enterprise = @country.enterprises.build(params[:enterprise])`

write :

`@enterprise = @country.enterprises.build(enterprise_params)`

meaning: the name of the action

EDIT: Hence - it's not going through the params.require.permit validation

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your explanation also.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the line to:

```
@enterprise = @country.enterprises.build(enterprise_params)
```